# Bottom: 0 - weird behavior when zooming

Tags: css

I am experiencing some weird behavior when zooming out on my webpage. I have some `div`s holding a title and `<p>`overlay. When the user hovers over the `div`, I want the `<p>`(in the overlay) to show, and when the user is not hovering, I want the `<p>` not to show.

This works fine in when the user is at a 0 zoom in the browser, but when the user zooms out, I can see the `<p>` section. Whilst zoomed out I can increase the `bottom` to correct for this, but there has to be something I missing.

Is there anyway to keep the `<p>` hidden when zoomed out?

I understand this must sound crazy so I did a crude JSFiddle to show what I am talking about. The weird thing is that when zooming out on JSFiddle the problem I am having in my browser (safari) is not happening on their site.

http://jsfiddle.net/FB2TM/

Any help would be appreciated!

I should have mentioned that I plan on animating the mouse over effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is happening because the browser is not resizing the text proportionally ending up with text larger than it should. You will also experience different text sizes over different browsers when resizing.

I find that the best solution is to do it differently by completely hiding the text that is not supposed to show:

```
.box {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background-color:aqua;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.caption {
  width:200px;
  color:white;
  background-color:black;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.caption p {
  display: none;
}

.box:hover .caption {
  bottom:0;
}

.box:hover .caption p {
  display: block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FB2TM/2/

Comment: Is there anyway to animate `display`?

Comment: @Quoid You can't animate the display with CSS. The only way I've found was to use javascript/jQuery. Find the height of the hidden element (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345784/jquery-get-height-of-hidden-element-in-jquery) then set the initial CSS (http://api.jquery.com/css/) and finally perform the animation with animate (http://api.jquery.com/animate/) or any of the shorthand jQuery animation functions.

Comment: @Quoid you can also check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13037637/css3-animation-and-display-none if you are able to set a fixed height to the hidden element.

Answer (score 1):

Changing from your approach of hiding the text with a negative offset to just hiding the text you want to hide might change your css animation options a bit. It does allow for dropping the z-index from the css.

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="caption">
        <div class="title">THE TITLE</div>
        <p>These are words, I do not want them to show, until mouseover. When zooming out, I can see these words.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and your css to:

```
.box {
    background-color:aqua;
    height:200px;
    position: relative;
    width:200px;
}
.caption {
    background-color:black;
    bottom:0;
    color:white;
    position: absolute;
    width:200px;
}
.caption p {
    display: none;
}
.box:hover p {
    display: block;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FB2TM/1/)

Comment: Hey Jason, I should have mentioned in my original post that I was using animations. I actually used `display` originally, but I couldn't seem to figure out a way to animate it. When I use `bottom`, I can have a nice smooth css animation to raise and lower the caption on mouse hover.

Comment: I suspected that might be the case based on how things were constructed. Do you only see the issue in Safari or do you also see it in other browsers?

Comment: I can only speak to Safari/Chrome and Firefox on MacOS. It indeed only happens on Chrome/Safari and does not happen in Firefox...Hrmm, any idea why'd this would be?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use top and fix positions with margin-top. For example:

```
.caption {
    width:200px;
    color:white;
    background-color:black;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    top:100%;
    margin-top:-30px; //Height of THE TITLE
    position: absolute;
}
.box:hover .caption {
   margin-top:-116px; //Height of .caption
}
```

I think using bottom is not a good practice.

Here's an update to your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FB2TM/3/

Comment: Using `bottom` is not any more bad practice than using `top`. Or `left` or `right`. It just depends what you are trying to accomplish positioning-wise.