# Is it possible to use transitions with display none to display block

Tags: javascript, css, transition

I'm still developing a genius forum for my website. I want to add some fancy javascript effects. I don't want to use jQuery for now.

My problem is the following: I have an element which appears by checking if the value of the function is true or false. With those check my article shows or hides.

My question is: Is it possible to use transitions so that my block drops down like the way transitions do?

The first js function describes the check and the next function hides or show my article when the values are not empty.

```
    function CheckEmptyValues() {
    var inputFields = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    var textFields = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea');
    var postData = [inputFields, textFields];

    for(var i=0; i<postData.length; i++) {
        for(var j=0; j<postData[i].length; j++) {
            if(postData[i][j].value !== '') {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

function showPreview() {
    if (CheckEmptyValues() === false) {
        this.prevPost.style.display = "block";
    }
    else {
        this.prevPost.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

When my emptyvalues are false the article appears and if not, it disappears. But when this happens you see only show or hide, no further effect or something.

I want to make this something like this effect:  http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_transition1

The height value should start with 0 and end with 150 height or something like that.
Does anyone have a solution how to make this look cool?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't, `display` is defined as non animatable.

If you want workarounds, see [CSS3 Animation and Display None](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13037637/1529630).

Answer (score 1):

No, `display` doesn't come in `transition-property`. But, you can try `opacity` and for the `display:block` , put it in your `div:hover` or only `div` css.

Comment: sorry, not `visibility `, its `opacity`

Comment: the div is hidden by using display:none, not by using opacity:0, so I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: that effect is not what I was looking for:) You can compare it to the animate function of jQuery

Comment: I'm saying if you want transition, use `opacity` property instead of `display`  and as your requirements to make text appear in a `block`, in the `:hover` css make it  `display:block`. Look [fiddle now](http://jsfiddle.net/3k2La5ok/5/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3k2La5ok/6/ when you type something into the inputfield you see hide and showing a div

Comment: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3k2La5ok/9/) try the "firstname" input. Are you talking about something like this.

Comment: No, what you did was using an onclick function to hide or show the text beneath the input. What I want is a slowly animation of dropping down like I've shown in the mainpost. Is that even possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `opacity`, and set it to `0` or `1`:

```
this.prevPost.style.display = "block";
this.prevPost.style.opacity = 1;
```