# Play HTML Video after CSS Animation

Tags: html, css, html5-video, css-animations

This is a bit crazy, but I got a project where I couldn't use JS.

I have an mp4 that needs only to be played after the CSS animation is finished.
To be better explained, I need to hide the cover image, then play the video behind it.

Is there a way to play mp4 from CSS/HTML only?

**HTML**

```
  <div class="chute-background-image" style="background-image: url(./fg_bg.png);"></div>
  <div class="winning-video">
    <video>
      <source src="./room.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.chute-background-image {
  opacity: 1;
  animation: hide 1s linear forwards;
}
@keyframes hide {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    display: block;
  }
  99% {
    opacity: 0;
    display: block;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: CSS (or jQuery, for that matter) can't animate between ```display: none;``` and ```display: block;```.
Check this question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13037637/css-animation-and-display-none

Comment: Hey @PratikMalvi, yes I know. That's why I trick it using the animation's opacity. Anyway, that is not eh question. I am asking if it possible to play mp4 from css/html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it isn't possible to do this without JavaScript.

No play control API is available by CSS.

Comment: Right, is there any alternatives? Like updating the mp4 to GIF or anything?

Comment: No, there isn't.  What's your reasoning for not using a simple script?

Comment: I am just doing a re-skin of the existing Kiosk game, so there is a limitation that the kiosk doesn't allow any javascript. Thanks anyway Brad

Comment: How, specifically, does it not allow any JavaScript?

Comment: I am submitting the skin to someone from the Kiosk provider. And they will check it, not really sure how and why they do it.

Comment: You're out of luck then, at least for the specific question you asked.  It would be helpful though if you could show us what you're actually trying to do.  Perhaps we can suggest an alternative.  (For example, why not just put whatever this is in the video itself and just play the video?)

Comment: Maybe you could negotiate with the kiosk provider to add some JavaScript on their end that they can audit?  And then you can control it via some `data-*` attributes or something.

Comment: Thanks Brad, I might try to negotiate with the kiosk provider with the custom JS. We are creating a game, and we have an mp4 animation that only plays when the user is winning.